# How can I create a TamperMonkey script that edits an specific element

Tags: javascript, html, css, tampermonkey

After searching for hours I finally found how to even edit a element with TamperMonkey but whenever I run that script only the first line works please see the script and help.

```
document.getElementsByClassName("loginPanelTitle")[0]
.style.display="flex"; //works
.style.opacity="0.5"; //doesn't work
.style.align-items="center"; //doesn't work
.style.padding="4px 8px"; //doesn't work
.style.font-size="24px"; //doesn't work
.style.background-color="#000000"; //doesn't work
.style.border-radius="2px 2px 0 0"; //doesn't work
.style.border-bottom="1px solid #d3d3d3"; //doesn't work
```

})();

Comment: The `;` (semicolon) **ends** a statement. Leave it off of all but the last one.

Comment: Also things like `align-items` should be spelled `alignItems`.

Comment: Why not adding those properties in the `loginPanelTitle` class itself or create a new class and add to the element?

Comment: @Aditya Dave can't you use css file?

Comment: @לבנימלכה I was trying to customize elements of a web that I don't have admin access to.

Answer (score 1):

Use a variable to store the element reference

```
var element = document.getElementsByClassName("loginPanelTitle")[0];
element.style.display="flex";
element.style.opacity="0.5";
// etc
```

**Edit:** You'll also need to use brackets for `border-radius` and others that use a dash, or use the camelCase variant of them

```
element.style["border-radius] = "2px 2px 0 0";
```

or

```
element.style.borderRadius = "2px 2px 0 0";
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your solution and explanation ^_^ It is working great now.

Comment: i'm glad @AdityaDave - don't forget https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers if this does answer you